# Use child class members when looping through vector with auto

Tags: c++, vector

Is it possible to access the members of a child class when looping though a vector?

```
struct Object
{
    std::string name;
};

struct Rect : Object
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};

struct Circle : Object
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int radius;
}
```

Running the code below gives me the error `struct Object has no member named 'x'` which I'm guessing is because `auto&` sees it as an `Object`. Is there any way for the iterator to use the `Rect` members?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Object> objects;

    Rect r;
    r.name = "test";
    r.x = 1;
    r.y = 1;

    objects.push_back(r);

    for(auto& ob: objects)
    {
        std::cout << ob.x << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about [*object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Firstly, your `Rect` is being sliced when you copy it into the `std::vector`, so it is not a `Rect`. Secondly, the compiler can't know that a given `Object` is a `Rect`, so you'll need to `dynamic_cast` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, `auto` is just syntactic sugar. However, in your example, you are looping over the vector of `Object`s, so

```
for(auto& ob: objects)
{
    std::cout << ob.x << std::endl;
}
```

is the same as

```
for(Object& ob: objects)
{
    std::cout << ob.x << std::endl;
}
```

Your `Object` class does not have the `x` member (your `Rect` class, which is derived from `Object`, does), hence the error (you are experiencing [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)).

Answer (score 1):

C++ standard containers contains *objects* and not references as in other languages. That means that when you store a object for a subclass in the container, you just store an object obtained by the copy constructor (or the operator = depending of method used). So you only store a base class object that have neither the fields nor the methods from the subclass. This is called [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) as said by  Joachim Pileborg in its comment.

If you want to store subclass objects, you will have to use pointers (preferently unique_ptr or shared_ptr instead of raw pointers unless you have good reasons to use the latter)